# how to make id which is not a unfixed value in $("#") works?

Tags: jquery, html

My code as below:

```js
var tElement=document.getElementById("test");

for(i=0;i<num;i++) 
{
  var img=document.createElement('img');
  img.src="img.jpg";
  img.id="'r'+i";
  tElement.appendChild(img);
  Tclick(i);
}

function Tclick(num){

  $("'#r'+num").click(function (num) {
    $("#display").append("<img src='img2.jpg'>");
  });

}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

however, the application always say '#r'+num is unexpected error, I don't how to write it so that it can work. plz help me. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using variable's properly. Since `i` and `num` are variable you don't need to wrap it in quotes.

Use

```
img.id='r'+i;
```

instead of

```
img.id="'r'+i";
```

And

```
$('#r'+num)
```

instead of

```
$("'#r'+num")
```